# how to submit a form to another page in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, form-submit

I am developing a wordpress plugin , which submits a form to another page. But when I try to submit the form to another page , then that page returns some php error. My form code is below

```
echo "<form action='".plugins_url()."/wp_voting_poll/frontend_poll_process.php'     method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hide' value='$ques' />";
        $total_vote_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_result WHERE question_uid='$ques'" );
        if($ques!=""){
        echo "<table>";

        foreach($ans_data as $ans_res){

         //   $ans=$ans_res->answer;
         $answer_id=$ans_res->id;
         $type=$ans_res->answer_type;


               $vote_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_result WHERE answer_id='$answer_id'" );
                if($vote_count==0){
                    error_reporting(0);
                }
                $vote_percent=($vote_count*100)/$total_vote_count;
             echo "<tr> <td>";  
           echo "<div class='answer_div'>";    
               if($type==1){
             echo "<div class='input'><input type='radio' name='ans_name[]' value='$answer_id'/>".$ans_res->answer."<br/></div>";
             }
             elseif($type==0){

             echo "<div class='input'><input type='checkbox' name='ans_name[]' value='$answer_id'/>".$ans_res->answer."<br/></div>";
             }
             if($backend==0){
             echo "</td> <td>";


             echo "<h4> total vote counted $vote_percent% </h4>";

            // echo "<img src='$url' width='$width_img'/>";
             $bar=$vote_percent*5.9;
             echo "<img src='$url' height='10' width='$bar' />";        

             echo "</td></tr>";
             }
        }
        echo "</table>";

        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit vote' />";
        echo "</form>";
```

And this is my code of another page , which should process the form . But unfortunately it returns php error.

```
<?php

require_once("function_ip.php");
$vote_result=$_POST['ans_name'];
$uid=uniqid();
global $wpdb;
$table_vote=$wpdb->prefix."poll_answer_result";
$count=count($vote_result);
 $hidden=$_POST['hide'];

$ans_data=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT  * FROM $table_vote WHERE question_id='$hidden'" );

if($count>0){
foreach($vote_result as $vote_arr){

    $wpdb->insert($table_vote,
                array('answer_id' => $vote_arr,
                      'ip' =>get_client_ip(),  
                      'question_uid' => $hidden
                        ));
 }

}

?>
```

Comment: Show the PHP error. Enable debugging in wp-config and display those errors as well. Also paste the errors from your php error log file

Comment: I am receiving these error where I submitted the form,


 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\wordpress_plugin\wp-content\plugins\wp_voting_poll\frontend_poll_process.php on line 7


Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\wordpress_plugin\wp-content\plugins\wp_voting_poll\frontend_poll_process.php on line 11

Comment: Contact the plugin developer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Wordpress has a generic handler to deal with all forms - `admin-post.php`.

If you include a hidden field in your form called `action`, you can then hook in to a function of your choice with all the goodness of wordpress included.

```
echo "<form action='".get_admin_url()."admin-post.php' method='post'>";

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='submit-form' />";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='hide' value='$ques' />";

    { Enter the rest of your first block of code from above here }

echo "</form>";
```

And then in your `functions.php` file (or any other `php` file that you have included via `functions.php`), you can use this method.

```
add_action('admin_post_submit-form', '_handle_form_action'); // If the user is logged in
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_submit-form', '_handle_form_action'); // If the user in not logged in
function _handle_form_action(){

    { Enter your second block of code from above here }

}
```

I'm not sure if you require a redirect once you reach your desired destination, but that can be easily accounted for if you do.

And one final question - is this form on the front end, or in the admin area? Not that it should make a difference that this answer, I'm just curious...

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is solved. My form is in front end.

Comment: You're welcome. That's cool about the front end. I was just curious as if it was in the admin area, there was some bits you could to to make submitting forms even easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your `frontend_poll_process.php` page is getting called out of the WordPress environment, therefore returning an error on `$wpdb->get_results()`.

You can add your code to a plugin or `functions.php` using hooks:

```
<?php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'so_19997913' ); 

function so_19997913() {
  require_once("function_ip.php");
  $vote_result = $_POST['ans_name'];
  $uid = uniqid();
  global $wpdb;
  $table_vote = $wpdb->prefix . "poll_answer_result";
  $count = count( $vote_result );
  $hidden = $_POST['hide'];

  $ans_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT  * FROM $table_vote WHERE question_id='$hidden'" );

  if ( $count > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $vote_result as $vote_arr ) {

      $wpdb->insert( $table_vote, array('answer_id' => $vote_arr,
        'ip' => get_client_ip(),
        'question_uid' => $hidden
      ) );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have also guessed that. But what should I do for get rid of this problem ?? I know one solution, that is put the form processing code in same page where the form is located. But I do not want that. I want to process the code in different page

Comment: you have used "after_setup_theme" in add_action. But its not a theme .Its a plugin. I want to be done is that, when I will activate the plugin this function (so_19997913) will run under wp environment.

Comment: it does not matter. I pasted it from a code I used which was in a plugin too.

Comment: I am having same problem yet

Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in C:\wamp\www\wordpress_plugin\wp-content\plugins\wp_voting_poll\frontend_poll_process.php on line 4

And I think its for same reason. add_action is outside of wp environment. But dont know the solution :(

Comment: Thanks for try to help me. But if I put my processing codes in main plugin file then it hampers my goal. I need to process the code in different page.